# Twitter Card API - Open twitter dialog via javascript and set meta tags dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter, twitter-card

How to call/create Twitter Card and set meta values dynamically instead of getting or declaring the meta data from head section. 
Just like the below code implementation.

```
FB.ui({
   method: 'share_open_graph',
   action_type:'og.shares',
   action_properties: JSON.stringify({
      'og-title':'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
      'og-image':'image-url'
   })
})
```

How can we implement this with Twitter Card API?
*Note: I'm trying to implement twitter Sharing with Image Preview, with dynamic image/content based on id selected.

Comment: this is Facebook code

Comment: Yes. I know. What I'm trying to say is that is there a sample code snippet similar to that code? Instead of open graph for facebook, I need the twitter card functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter cards require that your HTML meta tags are static in the web page - the card crawler is unable to execute Javascript. There's no other way to do this, you have to have the tags inserted on the server side before the crawler picks them up.